# What might be causing leaks in my roof and ceiling?

Tags: leak, ceiling, roof

We had a new roof put onto our kitchen extension because water marks were appearing on the ceiling.  For a year, this seemed to stop any further water coming through.  in the past week or so more water has been coming through and has actually caused rips in the paper covering the ceiling and also you can see a grid of where the water seems to be running down the joists - quite extensive and worrying especially with more rain to come.

**We are trying to get hold of the roof people as it is under guarantee**, but I think we need to address the potential problems being caused with wet joists as this seems to be getting worse each day with more wet patches and more worryingly is now going underneath one of the upstairs bedrooms.

Does anyone know what I should have looked at in the first instance?  I don't think the roofers do internal stuff so may not be much help.  I feel I will need to call someone else out and quickly as I don't want some serious damage to occur - I've not had to deal with this kind of issue before.

Thanks

Comment: Just to add more - there are cracks on the outside wall of the upstairs extension which stretches out across about half of the downstairs extension.  This wall is above where most of the water stains and leaking are in the kitchen below.  So I am not sure if there is one professional who can deal with everything but it seems to be a mixture of:  Water damage internally, external cracks in the masonry and potentially roof damage although it is new...

Comment: I would contact your home-insurance company and ask for their advice.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick That seems so obvious now, but that is a great suggestion - I kind of forgot that insurance is there for a reason and not just something you have to pay for!

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Without a detailed description of the structure, and/or photos, all that can be said is speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the roofing company had ceased to exist which was why it was difficult to get hold of them.

I got a reputable building company to sort out the cracks in the walls and weatherproof the render - they did an amazing job and they even found a fault in the way the new roof was fitted... and fixed it for free.  The fault was that the new roof was just a new covering (although well fitted and looked good to the untrained eye), but it required some lead flashing (like a skirt) to force water run-off from the walls to run onto the roof and towards the drain/drainpipe.  Without the flashing the water was allowed to run between the roof covering and the wall itself, hence leaking underneath in particularly wet weather.  The issue never returned.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the roofers should take care of the originating problem if you have a guarantee.

Also, be aware that most any kind of do-it-yourself fixes could be construed as voiding the guarantee.

The OP says you are "trying" to contact the roofers.  I don't really get that part.  Certainly there must be a way to contact them quickly, as it is in their best interests to respond quickly to prevent further damage that they may be liable for.

The OP says you "think" they might not cover internal issues.  The only way to be sure of that is to read the insurance repairs.

Generally, if you took them to court and it was obvious that their installation caused the internal damage, you would have a strong case that it is their responsibility.

Comment: I'd contact your state's Construction Contractors Board (CCB) and register a complaint against the company and the registered owners of the roofing company. That way, when they start a new roofing company the claim will follow them because of their names. By the way, the original company should have insurance and a bond (albeit small) that you can attach. The CCB board can help you complete the form, hear the claim and help you claim the bond.